# UI buttons will not show/hide using a timer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app that functions as a Bluetooth remote control. The interface has several buttons. In the Settings window, I have a way to enable and disable certain sets of buttons. When I change this setting and return to the View Controller with the buttons, I'd like it to add/remove the necessary buttons automatically.

I can do this manually with a button press (manualRefreshButton) and it works just fine. However, if I try to run the function in any other way, such as a timer, it will not cause the buttons to show/hide as needed. It does, however, print to the console every time regardless, so I know the timer is being executed.

I'd tried to run 'refreshView' upon closing the Settings view controller, as well as tried running it as a timer as shown in the code, both with the same result. I get my printed text in the console window, but the buttons never hide unless I manually press that 'manualRefreshButton'.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBOutlet var btnUpOne: UIButton?
@IBOutlet var btnUpTwo: UIButton?
@IBOutlet func manualRefreshButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     refreshView()
}

var timer: Timer?
func runTimer() {
     if timer == nil {
          self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }
}

func loop() {
     refreshView()
}

func refreshView() {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          print("Refreshing...")
          if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "buttonsSetting") == 0
          {
               self.btnUpOne?.isHidden = false
               self.btnUpTwo?.isHidden = true
               print("Button One Visible, Button Two Hidden")
          }
          else if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "buttonsSetting") == 1
          {
               self.btnUpOne?.isHidden = false
               self.btnUpTwo?.isHidden = false
               print("Button One Visible, Button Two Visible")
          }
          print("Refresh Complete")
     }
}
```

Comment: No need for the timer. Simply call `refreshView()` from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: BTW - change the outlet declarations to use `!` instead of `?` then remove all of the `?` when accessing those properties.